# Transfering token balance away from a smart contract

Tags: solidity, truffle

For some reason I am really struggling to get an ERC20 token balance to transfer away from a smart contract, after being sent to it.

Truffle tests are passing OK

```
const { expect, assert } = require('chai');

// Import utilities from Test Helpers
const { BN, expectEvent, expectRevert, constants } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

// Load compiled artifacts
const Oracle = artifacts.require('Oracle');
const LottoGame = artifacts.require('LottoGame');
const LottoToken = artifacts.require('LottoToken');

// Start test block
contract('LottoGame', function ([ creator, other ]) {
  let accounts;
  let oracle;
  let token;
  let contract;

  before(async function () {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    oracle = await Oracle.new({ from: creator });
    contract = await LottoGame.new(oracle.address, { from: creator });
    token = await LottoToken.new(creator, { from: creator });
    decimals = web3.utils.toBN(18);
  });

  it('should allow accounts to buy tickets', async function () {
    let expected, actual;

    let maxPlayers = web3.utils.toBN('3');
    let maxTicketsPlayer = web3.utils.toBN('10');
    let gameFeePercent = web3.utils.toBN('0');//web3.utils.toBN('1').mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
    let ticketPrice = web3.utils.toBN('1').mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
    let numberOfTickets = web3.utils.toBN('10');
    let gameFeeAddress = accounts[8];

    // Start game for LottoToken, exactly one token per entry,
    // max three players, max one ticket per player.
    let game0 = await contract.startGame(

      // Token address
      token.address,

      // Game fee address
      gameFeeAddress,

      // Game fee percent
      gameFeePercent,

      // Ticket price
      ticketPrice,

      // Max players
      maxPlayers,

      // Max player tickets
      maxTicketsPlayer,

      {from: accounts[0]}
    )

    // console.log(game0.logs[0].args.gameNumber);
    let game0Log = game0.logs[0].args;
    expect(game0Log.tokenAddress).to.eql(token.address);
    expect(game0Log.feeAddress).to.eql(gameFeeAddress);
    expect(game0Log.gameNumber).to.be.bignumber.equal('0');
    expect(game0Log.feePercent).to.be.bignumber.equal(gameFeePercent);
    expect(game0Log.ticketPrice).to.be.bignumber.equal(ticketPrice);
    expect(game0Log.maxPlayers).to.be.bignumber.equal(maxPlayers);
    expect(game0Log.maxTicketsPlayer).to.be.bignumber.equal(maxTicketsPlayer);

    // Seed accounts for testing
    await token.approve(
      accounts[0],
      web3.utils.toBN(1000000).mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals)),
      {from: accounts[0]}
    )

    let approveAmount = web3.utils.toBN(10000).mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
    // await token.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[1], approveAmount, { from: accounts[0] })
    await token.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[1], approveAmount, { from: accounts[0] })
    await token.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[2], approveAmount, { from: accounts[0] })
    await token.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[3], approveAmount, { from: accounts[0] })
    await token.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[4], approveAmount, { from: accounts[0] })

    let approveAmount100K = web3.utils.toBN(100000).mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
    await token.approve(contract.address, approveAmount100K, {from: accounts[0]});
    await token.approve(contract.address, approveAmount100K, {from: accounts[1]});
    await token.approve(contract.address, approveAmount100K, {from: accounts[2]});
    await token.approve(contract.address, approveAmount100K, {from: accounts[3]});
    await token.approve(contract.address, approveAmount100K, {from: accounts[4]});

    // Approve and buy 1 ticket for A1
    let game0A1Ticket = await contract.buyTicket(
      
      // Game number
      game0Log.gameNumber,
      
      // Number of tickets
      numberOfTickets,
      
      {from: accounts[1]}
    )

    let game0A1TicketLog = game0A1Ticket.logs[0].args;
    expect(game0A1TicketLog.playerAddress).to.be.bignumber.equal(accounts[1]);
    expect(game0A1TicketLog.gameNumber).to.be.bignumber.equal('0');
    expect(game0A1TicketLog.playerCount).to.be.bignumber.equal('1');
    expect(game0A1TicketLog.ticketCount).to.be.bignumber.equal(numberOfTickets);

    // Check contract balance (pot)
    let contractBalance = await token.balanceOf.call(contract.address, {from: accounts[1]});
    console.log(contractBalance);
    // return;
    expect(contractBalance).to.eql(web3.utils.toBN('10').mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals)));

    // Number of game players increases by one
    expected = web3.utils.toBN('1');
    actual = await contract.totalGames({from: accounts[1]});
    expect(actual).to.be.bignumber.equal(expected);

    // Buy second ticket for A1 (should fail)
    try {
      await contract.buyTicket(
      
        // Game number
        game0Log.gameNumber,
        
        // Number of tickets
        numberOfTickets,
        
        {from: accounts[1]}
      );
      assert.fail('The transaction should have thrown an error');
    } catch (err) {
      assert.include(
        err.message,
        "Exceeds max player tickets, try lower value",
        "The error message should contain 'Exceeds max player tickets, try lower value'"
      );
    }
    
    // Approve and buy 1 ticket for A2
    await contract.buyTicket(
      
      // Game number
      game0Log.gameNumber,
      
      // Number of tickets
      numberOfTickets,
      
      {from: accounts[2]}
    )


    // Approve and buy 1 ticket for A3
    await contract.buyTicket(
      
      // Game number
      game0Log.gameNumber,
      
      // Number of tickets
      numberOfTickets,
      
      {from: accounts[3]}
    )
    
    // Buy 1 ticket for A4 (should fail)
    try {
      await contract.buyTicket(
      
        // Game number
        game0Log.gameNumber,
        
        // Number of tickets
        numberOfTickets,
        
        {from: accounts[4]}
      );
      assert.fail('The transaction should have thrown an error');
    } catch (err) {
      assert.include(
        err.message,
        "Too many players in game",
        "The error message should contain 'Too many players in game'"
      );
    }


    contractBalance = await token.balanceOf.call(contract.address, {from: accounts[1]});
    console.log(contractBalance);

    expect(contractBalance).to.eql(web3.utils.toBN('30').mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals)));



    let approveAmount3333 = web3.utils.toBN(1000000).mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
    await token.approve(contract.address, approveAmount3333, {from: accounts[0]});


    // Choose a random winner
    let game0EndGame = await contract.endGame(
      
      game0Log.gameNumber,
      
      {from: accounts[0]}
    );

    let game0EndGameLog = game0EndGame.logs[0].args;
    expect(game0EndGameLog.tokenAddress).to.be.bignumber.equal(token.address);
    // expect(game0EndGameLog.winnerAddress).to.eql(accounts[1]);
    expect(game0EndGameLog.gameNumber).to.be.bignumber.equal('0');
    expect(game0EndGameLog.pot).to.be.bignumber.equal(web3.utils.toBN((ticketPrice * numberOfTickets) * 3));



    // Check game zero states
    game0State = await contract.getGameState.call(
      game0EndGameLog.gameNumber,
      {from: accounts[1]}
    );

    expect(game0State.status).to.eql(false);
    // Needs fee offset calc
    // expect(game0State.pot).to.be.bignumber.equal(game0EndGameLog.pot);
    expect(game0State.playerCount).to.be.bignumber.equal(web3.utils.toBN('3'));
    // Each player bought one ticket each
    expect(game0State.ticketCount).to.be.bignumber.equal(web3.utils.toBN('30'));
    expect(game0State.maxPlayers).to.be.bignumber.equal(maxPlayers);
    expect(game0State.maxTicketsPlayer).to.be.bignumber.equal(maxTicketsPlayer);
    expect(game0State.ticketPrice).to.be.bignumber.equal(ticketPrice);
    expect(game0State.feeAddress).to.be.bignumber.equal(gameFeeAddress);
    expect(game0State.tokenAddress).to.be.bignumber.equal(token.address);
    // expect(game0State.winnerAddress).to.be.bignumber.equal(token.address);


    // Get last game winner
    // actual = await contract.getGameLastWinner.call({from: accounts[1]});
    // expect(actual).to.be.properAddress;

    // Game count is one


    maxPlayers = web3.utils.toBN('3');
    maxTicketsPlayer = web3.utils.toBN('2');
    gameFeePercent = web3.utils.toBN('0');
    ticketPrice = web3.utils.toBN('2');
    numberOfTickets = web3.utils.toBN('2');
    gameFeeAddress = accounts[8];

    // Start game for LottoToken, exactly two token per entry,
    // max three players, max two tickets per player.
    let game1StartGame = await contract.startGame(

      // Token address
      token.address,

      // Game fee address
      accounts[9],

      // Game fee percent
      gameFeePercent,

      // Ticket price
      ticketPrice,
      
      // Max players
      maxPlayers,

      // Max player tickets
      maxTicketsPlayer,

      {from: accounts[0]}
    );

    let game1StartGameLog = game1StartGame.logs[0].args;
    // console.log(game1StartGameLog);

    // Another game test run, buying two tickets each
    count = await contract.buyTicket(
      
      // Game number
      game1StartGameLog.gameNumber,
      
      // Number of tickets
      numberOfTickets,
      
      {from: accounts[1]}
    );
    count2 = await contract.buyTicket(
      
      // Game number
      game1StartGameLog.gameNumber,
      
      // Number of tickets
      numberOfTickets,
      
      {from: accounts[2]}
    );
    count3 = await contract.buyTicket(
      
      // Game number
      game1StartGameLog.gameNumber,
      
      // Number of tickets
      numberOfTickets,
      
      {from: accounts[3]}
    );

    await contract.endGame(
      game1StartGameLog.gameNumber,
      {from: accounts[0]}
    );
    
  });
});
```

When I run the same `endGame` function via the UI, it reverts `RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

I have tried using `g.token.transfer()` and now `IERC20().transfer()`

`buyTicket` function works OK on UI, and I can see contract balance increasing as expected with a `balanceOf` call (testing with ticket cost of 1 (* 10 ** 18))

```
/**
   * @dev Allow a player to buy Nth tickets in `_gameNumber`, at predefined `g.ticketPrice` of `g.token`
   */
  function buyTicket(
    uint256 _gameNumber,
    uint256 _numberOfTickets
  ) external {
    Game storage g = games[_gameNumber];

    require(
      g.maxPlayers >= 0,
      "Invalid game"
    );
    require(
      g.status == true,
      "Game already ended"
    );
    require(
      _numberOfTickets > 0,
      "Buy at least 1 ticket"
    );

    // Ensure player has enough tokens to play
    uint256 _totalCost = g.ticketPrice * _numberOfTickets;
    require(
      g.token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= _totalCost,
      "Insufficent game token allowance"
    );

    // Marker for new player logic
    bool _isNewPlayer = false;

    // Current number of tickets that this player has
    uint256 _playerTicketCount = g.players[msg.sender];

    // First time player has entered the game
    if (_playerTicketCount == 0) {
      if (g.playerCount == g.maxPlayers) {
        revert("Too many players in game");
      }
      _isNewPlayer = true;
    }
    
    // Check the new player ticket count
    uint256 _playerTicketNextCount = _playerTicketCount + _numberOfTickets;
    require(
      _playerTicketNextCount <= g.maxTicketsPlayer,
      "Exceeds max player tickets, try lower value"
    );

    // Transfer `_totalCost` of `gameToken` from player, this this contract
    // _safeTransferFrom(g.token, msg.sender, address(this), _totalCost);
    g.token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _totalCost);

    // Add total ticket cost to pot
    g.pot += _totalCost;

    // If a new player (currently has no tickets)
    if (_isNewPlayer) {

      // Increase game total player count
      g.playerCount++;

      // Used for iteration on game player mapping, when resetting game
      g.playersIndex.push(msg.sender);
    }

    // Update number of tickets purchased by player
    g.players[msg.sender] = _playerTicketNextCount;

    // Add each of the tickets to an array, a random index of this array 
    // will be selected as winner.
    uint256 _i;
    while (_i != _numberOfTickets) {
      g.tickets.push(msg.sender);
      _i++;
    }

    // Increase total number of game player tickets
    g.ticketCount += _numberOfTickets;

    // Fire `TicketBought` event
    emit TicketBought(
      msg.sender,
      g.number,
      g.playerCount,
      g.ticketCount
    );
  }
```

and the `endGame` function that fails via UI due to my attempts to transfer

```
/**
   * @dev Ends the current game, and picks a winner
   */
  function endGame(
    uint256 _gameNumber
  ) external onlyRole(CALLER_ROLE) {
    Game storage g = games[_gameNumber];

    require(
      g.maxPlayers > 0,
      "Invalid game"
    );
    require(
      g.status == true,
      "Game already ended"
    );

    uint256 _pot = g.pot;
    uint256 _balance = g.token.balanceOf(address(this));
    require(
      g.pot <= _balance,
      "Not enough of game token in reserve"
    );

    // Close game
    g.status = false;

    // Pick winner
    uint256 _rand = _randModulus(100);
    uint256 _total = g.tickets.length - 1;
    uint256 _index = _rand % _total;
    g.winnerAddress = g.tickets[_index];

    // Send fees (if applicable)
    // if (g.feePercent > 0) {
    //   uint256 _feeTotal = (g.feePercent / 100) * _pot;

    //   // Transfer game fee from pot
    //   if (_feeTotal > 0) {
    //     g.token.transfer(g.feeAddress, _feeTotal);

    //     // Deduct fee from pot value
    //     _pot -= _feeTotal;
    //   }
    // }

    // Send pot to winner
    // g.token.transfer(g.winnerAddress, _pot);
    IERC20(g.tokenAddress).transfer(g.winnerAddress, _pot);

    // @todo Trim superfluous game data for gas saving
    totalGamesEnded++;

    // Fire `GameEnded` event
    emit GameEnded(
      g.tokenAddress,
      g.winnerAddress,
      g.number,
      _pot
    );
  }
```

Game struct

```
/**
   * @dev Game record struct
   */
  struct Game {

    /**
     * @dev Is game running?
     */
    bool status;

    /**
     * @dev Number assigned to the game (sequental, based on total games)
     */
    uint256 number;

    /**
     * @dev Total value of token pot
     */
    uint256 pot;

    /**
     * @dev Number of players in the current game
     */
    uint256 playerCount;

    /**
     * @dev Number of all player tickets in the current game
     */
    uint256 ticketCount;

    /**
     * @dev Maximum number of players allowed in the game
     */
    uint256 maxPlayers;

    /**
     * @dev Maximum number of tickets per player
     */
    uint256 maxTicketsPlayer;

    /**
     * @dev Single ticket price
     */
    uint256 ticketPrice;

    /**
     * @dev Percentage (hundredth) of the pot will go to `gameFeeAddress`.
     * Zero value disables feature
     */
    uint256 feePercent;

    /**
     * @dev Owner address of the game
     * @todo Allow people to run their own games? Risky?, sure.
     */
    // address ownerAddress;

    /**
     * @dev Destination for the game fee tokens
     */
    address feeAddress;

    /**
     * @dev ERC-20 token address for game tickets
     */
    address tokenAddress;

    /**
     * @dev Address of the game winner
     */
    address winnerAddress;

    /**
     * @dev List of individual player tickets
     */
    address[] tickets;

    /**
     * @dev Cross reference for `Game` struct `players` mapping
     */
    address[] playersIndex;

    /**
     * @dev List of unique game players
     */
    mapping (address => uint256) players;

    /**
     * @dev The game token that players will play for.
     */
    IERC20 token;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was hitting an overflow, switched to using `SafeMath`, and got the transfers working as expected with `g.token.transfer`